# cite.sty file is missing

Tags: miktex, texmaker, missing

I'm a fresh user of Latex systems. My problem is as follow:

I'm using Texmaker 5.0.4 program to execute my .tex files, and I've been told that I can find all packages I will need to compile my .tex files by downloading Miktex, so I downloaded the latest version of Miktex 2.9 to use its packages in compiling my .tex files with Texmaker.

The problem was when I tried to compile a .tex file using Texmaker, it showed me a "package installation" message that the required file "cite.sty" is missing.It seemed to me that Texmaker can't see the packages that I downloaded with Miktex, so I tried to set up the local package repository in my Texmaker to be MikTex but it showed an error message that it is not a local package repository.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Do you install the complete `MikTeX` or the basic version? Also, try the installation in `Administrator` mode...

Comment: If you installed the basic MiKTeX quite a lot packages will be missing and it is quite normal that MiKTeX asks you if it should install them, when you use them. Simply say yes or go to the package manager and install every package.